# How to use total probability law on this specific question apart from just counting.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There are ten cards numbered 1 to 10.

Comment: Post edit:  that method is solid and should work.  What answer did you get?

Comment: 0.5 or 50%. Not really sure if it's right.

Comment: Well....I guess I am not sure what you mean by "keeps it back in the deck".  Does the boy replace the card he drew or not?

Comment: The boy picks it up reads the number m and then keeps it back. Now the girl gets to select from 10 cards again to read another number n. But both of them choose from 10 cards.

Comment: $0.5$ looks correct for the conditional probability $N\ge M$ given $M$ is even but looks too high for $N>M$ given $M$ is even.  Though $0.5$ also looks correct for the conditional probability $N\gt M$ given $M$ is odd

Comment: "keeps it back" is hard to parse.  But it seems the boy is replacing the card, in which case your answer is correct.  We get $\frac 15\times \frac {1+3+5+7+9}{10}=\frac 12$.

Comment: @lulu - are you sure about that?  Even cards are like to be higher on average than odd cards

Comment: i hope so. but why is "keeps it back" hard to parse. It simply is that he picks one up and keeps it back i guess. But anyways, i was worried if the approach was right.

Comment: @Henry  I don't find it intuitive one way or the other, I just did the calculation.  Without replacement, the answer is $\frac 59$.

Comment: @Parrot "puts it back" is easier to understand then "keeps it back"

Comment: @lulu why your expression rather than $\frac 15\times \frac {0+2+4+6+8}{10}$?

Comment: @Parrot  "keeps" means "retains".  If you said the boy "keeps the card" it would mean that he does not put it back. "keeps it back" really doesn't make sense.

Comment: oh yes. I might have mingled a bit of words there. My bad.

Comment: @Henry  If the boy draws $m$ then there are $m-1$ cards $<m$ the girl can draw, hence the probability that the boy has the higher one is $\frac {m-1}{10}$.

Comment: @Henry Oh, I'm sorry.  I misread the question.  I computed the probability that $m$ was greater but it asks for the probability that $n$ is greater.  Should really put my glasses on.

Comment: @Henry exactly. Could have sworn that last $n$ was an $m$.  Sorry for the blunder.

Comment: @Parrot  To stress:  Henry is correct.  I computed the probability that $m>n$.  That's not what you asked for.  You asked for the probability that $n>m$.  Since a tie is possible, those answers you can't instantly deduce one from the other.

Comment: This is bizarre! Your edit, at some point after I answered the question, has made the question meaningless. You just removed the original question and your attempt. Please refrain from doing so in the future. Either reinstate the original question or unaccept my answer so I can delete it as my answer does not make any sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$n$ must be greater than $m$ and $m$ is even. So it should be,

$P (n \gt m) = \frac{1}{5} \cdot \left(\frac{8}{10} + \frac{6}{10} + \frac{4}{10} + \frac{2}{10} + \frac{0}{10}\right) = \frac{2}{5}$

If $m = 2$ with probability $1/5$ then $n \in (3, 10)$ and probability of that is $8/10$. Similarly we add probability of $n \gt m$ for $m = 4, 6, 8$ and $10$.